# CAS 3.5.2 OpenID configuration

Tags: configuration, openid, cas

I tried to configure jasig CAS 3.5.2 with OpenId, by following the directions from https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/OpenID, but no luck, it didn't work.
Any body could provide me a configuration example or working CAS (OpenId) war file?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Last time I made tests, it was working. Would you mind trying this demo : https://github.com/leleuj/cas-openid-demo ?

Comment: Thank you jleleu, I did try your cas-openid-demo, but I coundn't make it work.  I have some questions: **bold**fill the form with http://localhost:8080/cas/openid/leleuj (replace leleuj by your username) and click the **bold**   I don't know the 'username' stands for. Is it a email address?    While testing, it still using default username==password authentication.   Mr. Jleleu, could you please provide more information on your demo.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, the username is the login you enter on the login page and the authentication handler excepts a password equals to the login...